# Get only not-equal part of lines

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file like

```
foo 123
keyword-a some text I dont know in advance text to show
keyword-a some text I dont know in advance some other arbitrary text
keyword-a some text I dont know in advance 99 more to show
keyword-b loremipsum 1
keyword-b loremipsum 2 3 show me
```

I use grep to get all required keyword lines.

How can I get **only the not-equal part of the matching lines**?
For example for *keyword-a* I'd like to get:

```
text to show
some other arbitrary text
99 more to show
```

For *keyword-b* I'd like to get:

```
1
2 3 show me
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's difficult to give an answer without having any idea of what `some text I dont know in advance` actually is. It's clear that it's a placeholder bu as what's there can be anything, there's no way to give a command that's based on any pattern to be excluded or used as a delimited. One can give an answer based on the string `some text I dont know in advance but it may not be functional with what's actually there.

Comment: Well, "some text I dont know in advance" is exaclty what it claims to be. I cannot forsee what text will be there as the text file to be processed will come from some external source. For the sake of having an example to explain what is required I put in this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here is a fairly common task, called finding the Longest Common Sequence (LCS), also known as the "Longest Common Substring problem".  This is often used for tasks like printing the longest common directory for a set of pathnames or URIs.  In your case, you want to do the opposite of that, output the parts of each line that **aren't** part of that longest sequence .

You could write your own algorithm to find the LCS in any language you like, but perl already has a module that implements it called [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff).  This module is not included with the perl standard library and has to be installed with `cpan` or from a distro package (e.g. on Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu and Mint, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install libalgorithm-diff-perl`. Other distros may or may not have it packaged)

The following code reads in each input line, splits it into an array of words, and calculates the size of the longest common sequence for each keyword (the first word on each line).

Once it has read all input lines, it re-reads the input from the beginning again and prints the non-common portion of each input line.  If a keyword has only been seen once (e.g. `foo` in your input sample), it just prints that line as-is (delete or comment out the `if`-block that does this if you want unique keywords to be excluded from the output).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Algorithm::Diff qw(LCS_length);

my %keywords;
my %LCS;

# get input filename(s)
my @input_files = @ARGV;

# First read in each line and figure out the longest common
# sequence for each keyword
# NOTE: this code assumes that two samples for each keyword
# is enough (i.e. it compares only the first two input lines
# which have the same keyword)
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my @words = split;
  my $keyword = $words[0];
  
  if (defined $keywords{$keyword}) {
   if (! defined($LCS{$keyword}) ) {
      $LCS{$keyword} = LCS_length(
         \@{ $keywords{$keyword}->[0] },
         \@words
      );
    };
  } else {
    push @{ $keywords{$keyword} }, \@words;
  };
};

# process the same input file(s) again to print the
# non-common portions of each line
push @ARGV, @input_files;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my @words = split;
  my $keyword = $words[0];
  
  # if the keyword is unique, just print the line
  if (! defined($LCS{$keyword})) {
    print $_, "\n";
    next;
  };
  
  my $len = $#words;
  my $lcs = $LCS{$keyword} - 1;
  $lcs++ if $lcs == 1;
  print join(" ", $keyword, @words[$lcs..$len]), "\n";
};
```

Sample output (after saving the script above as `not-equal.pl` and making it executable with `chmod`):

```
$ ./not-equal.pl input.txt 
foo 123
keyword-a text to show
keyword-a some other arbitrary text
keyword-a 99 more to show
keyword-b 1
keyword-b 2 3 show me
```

Note: because it is printing an array of words joined by a space, **any** sequences of 2-or-more whitespace characters in an input line will be transformed to a **single space character**.  If this is not what you want, you'll have to implement your own LCS algortihm - start by googling for "Longest Common Sequence" (or "Longest Common Substring") and see both https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring.

---

BTW, as written this script can not process stdin as it needs to re-read the input files again and stdin is not seekable.  It **is** possible to write a version capable of processing stdin (in fact, my first version of this script did that) but you'd have to read each line into an array during the first loop and then iterate over the array elements for the second loop.  Depending on the size of your input file(s), this could consume a lot of memory.

Here's my first version, which keeps on storing each input line into the %keywords hash (instead of storing only the first entry).  The main problem with it is that hashes are inherently un-ordered so the order of output will be semi-random (or, as I have done, sorted by the keywords).  This is the reason I changed it to just read the input file(s) twice - one pass to figure out the LCS, then a second pass to produce the output (even though your sample input was already sorted...I don't know if that will be the case for your real data).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Algorithm::Diff qw(LCS_length);

my %keywords;
my %LCS;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my @words = split;
  my $keyword = $words[0];

  if (defined $keywords{$keyword} && ! defined($LCS{$keyword}) ) {
    $LCS{$keyword} = LCS_length(
      \@{ $keywords{$keyword}->[0] },
      \@words
    );
  };

  push @{ $keywords{$keyword} }, \@words;
};

foreach my $keyword (sort keys %keywords) {
  foreach my $line (keys @{ $keywords{$keyword} } ) {
    my @words = @{ $keywords{$keyword}[$line] };
    if (!defined($LCS{$keyword})) { 
      print join(" ", @words), "\n"; 
       next
    };

    my $len = $#words;
    my $lcs = $LCS{$keyword} - 1;
    $lcs++ if $lcs == 1;
    print join(" ", $keyword, @words[$lcs..$len]), "\n";
  };
};
```

Comment: BTW, these scripts print the keyword with each line.  that's easily changed, but it's more useful to keep it in the output so you can pipe it into other scripts for further processing e.g. `./not-equal.pl input.txt | sed -n 's/^keyword-a //p'` to print only the keyword-a lines.

Comment: thank you very much! I was trying to avoid tmp files. I need to grep the initial file in advance.

Comment: so adding your first solution also is greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW, you can easily change the first script to be able to process stdin, using an array instead of a hash to avoid.  1. add `my @lines;` somewhere at the top of the script (e.g. immediately after `my %LCS;`).  2. add `push @lines, $_;` as the very last line **in** the first `while(<>) {` loop.  3. delete the `my @input_files = @ARGV;` and `push @ARGV, @input_files;` lines (and associated comments). 3. change the second `while(<>) {` line to `foreach (@lines) {`. The `chomp;` immediately after that is no longer needed (but is harmless) so you can delete that if you want.

Comment: Or, if you're comfortable working with arrays-of-arrays and array references (see the man pages for `perllol`, `perlref`, `perlreftut`, and `perldsc`) you could `push @lines, \@words` in the first loop and start the second loop with `foreach my $words (@lines)` to avoid having to re-split the line in the second loop. The second loop would require a few other minor changes (because it's using arrayref $words instead of array @words). That would improve performance (but that would only be important if it's reading many thousands of input lines).

Comment: Even if you're not comfortable, I recommend trying it anyway just to learn how.  Perl references are a fundamental concept and very important to understand if you want to be able to process multi-dimensional arrays and other data structures.  Just knowing how they work makes certain kinds of solutions obvious and straight-forward to implement.  BTW, both versions of the script above use a Hash-of-Array-of-Arrays data structure: %keywords - the keyword is the hash key and the value is an array (one element for each line being stored) of arrays (the words in a line)

Answer (score 0):

cas gave you the advanced luxury answer. For the case that you need it less bullet-proof, it can be easier with a little assumption: If (like in your example) all lines with the same keyword share the identical piece of common text and there are no two that share additional common characters (not `foo1`, `foo21` and `foo22`), a simple script will do like this `sed`

```
sed '/keyword-a/H;$!d;x
  s/^\(\n\)\(.*\)\(.*\n\)\2/\2\1\3\2/;:l
  s/^\(.*\)\(\n.*\n\)\1/\1\2/;tl
  s/^[^[:cntrl:]]*\n//'
```

The first line collects all keyword lines in the hold space, the second identifies the longest common start and places it at the beginning, the third line is looped to remove all occurrences, the forth removes the common start that is still at the beginning.

Comment: Got to love sed for it's easy to read syntax - almost thought it was brainfuck on first glimpse ;-) I check if I can live with the assumtions made but sed proably cannot compete with cas' soultion.

Answer (score 0):

As cas has put me on the right track and just for the fun of it I made this as a php-cli script. Reads file into memory so better not throw it at your finest 5+GB log file ;-)

Either pass file to process as argument or pipe into script:

```
$ grep keyword-a myfile.txt | php drop-longest-leading-common-substring.php
DEBUG: [DROPPED]                                     RESULT
DEBUG: [keyword-a some text I dont know in advance ] text to show
DEBUG: [keyword-a some text I dont know in advance ] some other arbitrary text
DEBUG: [keyword-a some text I dont know in advance ] 99 more to show

text to show
some other arbitrary text
99 more to show
```

Script contains some debug output, remove fwrite/DEBUG-lines for "production use".

```
<?php
// proof-of-concept script to remove longest common leading substring from file or piped input
// result output to STDOUT
// (remove all fwrite(STDERR,...) lines for real world usage)

// Get lines from passed file or STDIN    
if( ! empty($argv[1])) {
    if( ! is_readable($argv[1]) || | is_file($argv[1]) ) {
        fwrite(STDERR, 'Error: ' . $argv[1] . ' not readable. Abort.' . PHP_EOL);
        exit(1);
    }
    $lines = file($argv[1], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
} else {
    $lines = stream_get_contents(STDIN); // as string
    $lines = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+$/", '', $lines); // drop final CR|LF as it would add an empty array element with preg_split()
    $lines = preg_split('/(\r\n|\r|\n)/', $lines); // handle CRs and|or LFs
}

if(empty($lines)) {
    fwrite(STDERR, 'Nothing to process' . PHP_EOL);
    exit;
}

// no way the first non-common match is beyond shortest string's end
$strlen_shortest=PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $strlen_shortest=min($strlen_shortest, strlen($line));
}
fwrite(STDERR, 'DEBUG: shortest string in input: ' . $strlen_shortest . ' characters' . PHP_EOL);

$last_common_substring_at = $strlen_shortest;

// read n chars from all lines until substring differs
for($c = 1; $c <= $strlen_shortest; $c++) {
    fwrite(STDERR, 'DEBUG: ' . substr($lines[0],0,$c) . ' [' .  substr($lines[0],$c) . ']' . PHP_EOL);
    $line_parts=[];
    $line_part_last=false;
    foreach($lines as $line_key=>$line) {
        if( false !== $line_part_last) {
            if($line_part_last != substr($line,0,$c)) {
                fwrite(STDERR, 'DEBUG: ' . substr($line,0,$c)  . ' [' .  substr($line,$c) . ']' . PHP_EOL);
                fwrite(STDERR, 'DEBUG: ' . str_repeat(' ', $c-1) . '^ first difference at char ' . $c . PHP_EOL);
                $last_common_substring_at = $c-1;
                break 2;
            }
        } else {
            $line_part_last = substr($line,0,$c);
        }
    }
}

fwrite(STDERR, 'DEBUG: ' . PHP_EOL);
fwrite(STDERR, sprintf('DEBUG: %-' . ($last_common_substring_at +2) . 's %s' . PHP_EOL, '[DROPPED]', 'RESULT') );
foreach($lines as $line_key=>$line) {
    fwrite(STDERR, 'DEBUG: [' . substr($line,0,$last_common_substring_at) . ']');
    fwrite(STDERR, ' ');
    fwrite(STDERR, substr($line,$last_common_substring_at) . PHP_EOL);
}
    fwrite(STDERR, PHP_EOL);

// final result:
foreach($lines as $line_key=>$line) {
    echo substr($line,$last_common_substring_at) . PHP_EOL;
}
```